# Write Linux System Information to File

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, system-info

I'm very new to Ubuntu. In my brief experience, I've been increasingly impressed with whats available. Currently, I'm trying to log some system information periodically. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way I can do this from the command-line.

I know from the command line I can use the command `landscape-sysinfo` and it will display:

- System Load
- RAM memory Used
- RAM memory Available
- Hard Drive Space Used
- Hard Drive Space Available
- SWAP Usage

Is there a way that I can automatically write this stuff to a file called /logs/system-info.log every minute? If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relatively simple solution in principle:

1. Cron job that runs `landscape-sysinfo >> /logs/system-info.log` every minute
2. Configure logrotate for your `/logs/system-info.log` (so that your log file doesn't take over your server

Good luck!